How do I find cuneiform signs that aren't in the dictionary?
Going through Beckman's edition of The Anatolian Myth of Illuyanka, there are some signs in the transcription that I can't find in standard references. For example, EZEN is used as a logogram for "festival" (line 7), LÚGUDÚ for "priest" (line 1), and ULÙ in the compound LÚ.ULÙ.LU for "mortal" (line 20). But none of these signs have entries in the Hethitisches Zeichenlexikon.
I can make reasonable guesses as to what they're supposed to be. For example, the HZL has an entry for EZEN4:

Statt EZEN findet sich in den Bogazköy-Texten stets EZEN×ŠE, das - einem Vorschlag
R.Borgers folgend - hier mit EZEN4 umschrieben wird.
Instead of EZEN, the Boghazköy texts always contain EZEN×ŠE, which—following the suggestion of R. Borger—is here given the reading EZEN4.

So presumably this EZEN should actually be EZEN4. Similarly, under LÚ there's a compound LÚ.U19.LU meaning "mortal", so perhaps this ULÙ is the HZL's U19? Another edition has SANGA in place of GUDÚ, so maybe it's an alternate reading for that sign (which is in the dictionary)?
But this requires a lot of guesswork. Is there a better way to look up signs that aren't in the standard dictionaries? Or do I need to go find an autograph to figure out which signs were actually written there?

Are we quite sure that LÚ.ULÙ.LU means ‘mortal’ and not ‘yodelling’?

@JanusBahsJacquet: I know you're joking, but the original Sumerian word written with those signs was lulu = "man", "human being" (borrowed into Akkadian as lullû = "primeval man" mainly in mythic context), with the final LU sign included as a phonetic complement, i.e. a hint for how the preceding sign(s) should be read.

Short answer: Try another dictionary.

Remember that the same Sumero-Akkadian cuneiform signs used to write Hittite were also used for several other languages, most notably and obviously Sumerian and Akkadian. The actual shapes of the signs might vary, both between languages but even more between different eras, regions, media and writing styles (monumental, cursive, etc.), but there's a general continuity of sign identity (with occasional exceptions like signs splitting or merging) all the way from Sumerian proto-cuneiform to the abstract late Assyrian and Hittite sign forms.
Modern comprehensive cuneiform sign lists like Labat's Manuel d'Epigraphie Akkadienne and Borger's Mesopotamisches Zeichenlexikon also typically cover all (or at least most) known cuneiform signs regardless of which language(s) they were used for, and as a result, the modern assyriological sign names are also pretty much consistent between different languages using the cuneiform writing system. Thus, when looking up cuneiform signs, you shouldn't limit yourself just to resources for the specific language you're reading.

In particular, one convenient online source for cuneiform signs in the electronic Pennsylvania Sumerian Dictionary (ePSD). While the interface may be a bit quirky and outdated, it works quite well once you learn to use it.
For example, to look up the sign ULÙ in the ePSD, enter "ulu3" (remember that the acute and grave accents in cuneiform sign names are just shorthand for the subscripts 2 and 3) in the text box at the bottom of the page and select "SIGN" from the drop down menu to the right of it. Yes, "SIGN" is already shown as selected by default — click the menu anyway and select it. It's (old early 2000s Javascript) magic!
Doing this will open a frame (yes, I said it was an old website!) in the right sidebar showing that the ulu3 sign has the canonical (for ePSD at least) name URU×MIN, can also be read (at least) as ĝišgal, lu7, u18, uru17, gal3 (maybe), qal3, suk3, ul12 or zik3, and looks like this (in the modern font the site uses, which I believe is mostly based on late Sumerian / monumental Old Babylonian): 
There are also links you can click to see what Sumerian words the sign could be used to write (which could sometimes be useful even if you're reading Hittite, if you suspect you might be dealing with a sumerogram!), but let's ignore those for now.
Meanwhile, entering "u19" in the same box and again (re)selecting "SIGN" from the menu opens this page, which shows that u19 is simply an alternative name for the sign URU, which can also be read as ala, eri, iri, lu8, ri2, re2, ru9 or šigx (where the subscript "x" means that this reading hasn't been assigned a standard subscript number and is probably rare, controversial and/or geographically limited). It looks the same as the ulu3 = URU×MIN sign, just without the superposed MIN: 
BTW, if you click the full listing link in the sidebar for ulu3 = URU×MIN sign, you'll find an entry for "lu2-lu7lu = lulu [MAN]", saying:

lulu [MAN] (100x: ED IIIb, Old Akkadian, Ur III, Old Babylonian) wr. lu2-lu7; lu2-lu7lu "man; humanity" Akk. amēlu; lullû

and also showing the cuneiform signs for the various ways this Sumerian word was written. The "lu2-lu7lu" writing is exactly your LÚ.ULÙ.LU, just using a different name for the ulu3 = lu7 sign, and writing the final LU in a superscript to indicate that in Sumerian it was a phonetic complement used as a hint for how the previous signs should be pronounced.
It appears that LÚ.U19.LU (or lu2-lu8lu, as a sumerologist would probably transcribe those signs in context) is not an attested a way to write the word "lulu" in Sumerian, at least not as far as ePSD knows. However, given that U19 = URU is simply ULÙ = URU×MIN with two wedges omitted (and also a more common sign in general), it seems quite plausible that some Assyrian or Hittite scribe at some point decided to simplify the spelling of this sumerogram by using a simpler and more common sign instead of a rare variant.

Ps. The ePSD also has an entry for the sign ezen, showing that it has the common Sumerian reading "ezem [FESTIVAL]" and looks like this in Sumerian cuneiform: 
However, ePSD's entry for ezen4 is very sparse, only giving the canonical name EZEN×ŠE but no readings and not even a picture of the sign. This makes sense if (as the entry from HzL you quote suggests) this sign variant was a uniquely Hittite innovation and never used in Sumerian.
(This is confirmed by the fact that the only other spelling given for "ezem [FESTIVAL]" in ePSD is an Emesal "eye dialect" spelling i-ze-eĝ3, presumably reflecting a pronunciation something like "izeng".)
At least the name EZEN×ŠE is sufficiently descriptive that we can guess approximately what the sign must look like: it would look like EZEN with (something resembling) the sign ŠE () superimposed, presumably as a form of hatching (gunû, which BTW is another Sumerian word loaned into Akkadian and from there to modern assyriological jargon; or in this case perhaps more appropriately šeššig, even if at least early Sumerian šeššig didn't really look much like an actual superimposed ŠE).
Given that this EZEN4 = EZEN×ŠE sign apparently (according to HzL) occurs in complementary regional distribution with plain EZEN, it presumably is really just a scribal variant of the same sign with no actual difference in meaning. However, apparently it looks distinctive enough that it was deemed appropriate to assign it a separate subscript number.

Pps. I looked on CDLI for tablets containing the sign EZEN4, and found exactly one: Shilling 001 (P497367)
Looking at the photos of the tablet, the (single) EZEN4 sign is not too hard to find, but at least I really would not be able to tell it apart from an ordinary Neo-Assyrian EZEN:

Maybe, if I squint at it just right, I might be able to tell that there's something inscribed in the box formed by the horizontal and vertical wedges on the right half of the sign, but I sure would not be able to tell that it's supposed to be ŠE (and not one of the several other signs that can apparently also appear inscribed there).
Of course, this one example of EZEN4 I managed to find on CDLI might be damaged or otherwise not be representative of the typical appearance of the sign. But at least this suggests that telling EZEN and EZEN4 apart just by appearance might not always be trivial.

Addendum: I noticed that you also asked about LÚGUDÚ.
Searching ePSD for the sign "gudu2" doesn't turn up much, except that it's also a compound sign (gudu2 = SAG×UR) and is featured in a single entry that has nothing to do with priests of any kind. It would seem that LÚGUDÚ was not used as a priestly title in Sumerian.
Borger does list the sign (as #196), but only gives a bunch of lexical attestations and references to sources I don't have handy, while Labat has it indexed as #121 but curiously no actual entry for it — at least my 6th edition copy just jumps straight from sign #119 (KÀN) to #122 (MÁ)!
However, I did find a seemingly useful entry in Tischler's Hethitisches Handwörterbuch (2nd ed.), Appendix 1:

LÚGUDÚ lies LÚGUDU12 'Gesalbter' (Art Priester, LÚ"IM.ME"; heth. LÚtazzel(li)-, ?)

FWIW, ePSD doesn't recognize the sign gudu12, but Borger does have an index entry for it that reads:

gudu12 siehe 638 (heth. IM-ME)

where entry #638 reads:

638 AḪ-ME 
gudu4, gúda (AḪ-ME) = pašīšu, ein Priester. In der Kültepe-Texten = kumru, ein Priester. Cf. Menzel, Assyr. Tempel I 240.

with a sub-entry for:

 = gudu4/gúda-abzu(ZU-AB) = gudapsû, ein Priester.

(In case you're curious, the Chicago Assyrian Dictionary has entries for both pašīšu and kumru, although the latter is quite brief and only describes the spelling GUDU4 = kumru as attested in Old Assyrian.)
It's worth noting here that, while the Sumerian and Old Babylonian forms of the signs AḪ and IM look absolutely nothing alike, in Neo-Assyrian (and presumably Hittite) cuneiform they become very similar, differing in just a few wedges (and, based on checking a few modern fonts, with perhaps as much scribal variation within each sign as between them!). I'm not 100% sure if Borger and Tischler are actually suggesting that GUDU4 = AḪ-ME and GUDU12 = IM-ME are just variations of the same sign, but based on their very similar appearance, it seems at least plausible to me.
I'm also not 100% sure what Tishcler means by "lies LÚGUDU12", given that AFAIK the signs GUDÚ = SAG×UR and GUDU12 = IM-ME look nothing alike in any form of cuneiform writing. It might be that he's suggesting that Hittite scribes used these signs interchangeably based on their shared phonetic value, or it might be that he's suggesting that LÚGUDÚ is a modern transliteration mistake for LÚGUDU12. With a photo or line art of some cuneiform tablet where the supposed LÚGUDÚ appears, it should be easy enough to check what's actually written there, but so far I haven't found any.

To make matters worse, here's the Hethport transcription of the two fragments that include that line: KBo III.7 KBo XII.83. Neither of them has this GUDÚ sign!

That said, one of the fragments does have LÚ^GUDU12 in the Hethport transcription where Beckman has LÚ^GUDÚ, so I'm guessing it's a disagreement between transcription conventions. At least this explains why one edition has SANGA instead: if none of the fragments preserve that sign, SANGA makes sense to fill in the gap too.

BTW, I just actually read the paper you linked and noticed that it discusses the meaning of "{LÚ}GUDÚ" in Hittite on pp. 20–21, in particular disagreeing with its identification with the tazzelli priest and comparing it with the Akkadian pašīšu. What it doesn't say anything about is what this supposed Hittite GUDÚ sign actually looked like on clay (and in particular whether it actually looked more like IM-ME or SAG×UR).

There's also this one, which suggests that GUDU12 (IM.ME) is the Hittite equivalent of GUDU4 (AH.ME), and should be read in Hittite as kumra rather than tazzelli.
